# Problem in jQuery sending values with $.post

Tags: ajax, post, jquery

**EDITED: After two hours trying to solve my problem I was obfuscated, so I came to StackOverflow, I read related questions that did´nt solve my problem, and finally I asked help. I simplified my code and posted this question. Testing the code you gave me I could see where I was failing. That's embarrassing: just before calling $.post I was changing the content of the form div to show an ajax loader gif, so when $.post was called the inputs had been deleted.**

Hello. I´m testing jQuery AJAX functions, and I can´t send data by [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).
This is the process:

- form.php: a html form and a jquery script that send values by $.post and alerts the result
- process.php: a php script that receives the values, work with them and returns something.

FORM

```
<form action="#" method="post">
<label for="name">Your name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
<label for="email">Your email</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
<input type="button" value="send" id="btnSend" />
</form>
```

JQUERY

```
    function sendAjaxPost(){

        $.post('process.php',{
                name: $('#name').val(),
         email: $('#email').val()
         },
         function(data){
           alert(data);
         });
        }

$('#btnSend').click(function(){
   sendAjaxPost();
}
```

PROCESS.PHP

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
 echo $key . ' => ' . $value . '<br/>';
}
```

I can´t send $('#name').val(), but if I send a string everything works fine. I have alert $('#name').val() inside the jQuery function and it´s possible to read it. I have followed the sintaxis shown in [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Could someone give me a light? Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean when you say, " but if I send a string everything works fine." ??

Comment: Are you sure that input field is the only one on the DOM with id="name"?

Comment: @tsegay if I send in $.post-> name: 'My name', email: 'My email' instead of name: $('#name').val()

Comment: @lan Sure. I have tried $('input[name="name"]').val() too with the same result.

Comment: Updated my Answer and see if that can help. On my system with same configuration works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can read the input fields on the function, you can try this,

```
function sendAjaxPost(){
         name=$('#name').val();
         email=$('#email').val();
         alert(name);   
         alert(email);   
        //If this two alerts the name and email, try with $.get();
        $.post('process.php',{
                name: name,
                email:email
         },
         function(data){
           alert(data);
         });
        }
```

Comment: Aren´t you mixing JS and PHP sintax?. I have tried what you suggest with: var name = $('#name').val(); But it didn´t work

Comment: You are right. Your code work fine for me too. I found my error. I´m going to update my question. Thanks for your help!